# "to fulfill the word I had given" Idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> "It took me five years ***to fulfill the word I had given***"

Is the above sentence idiomatic?

***"to fulfill the word I had given"*** seems bit unidiomatic to me, I don't know why. I'm thinking that there could be some better and more idiomatic phrase in English to mean that.

The context is, I had told one of my friend that I would draw his picture but I didn't. After five years (now), I've drawn his picture and want to say the above statement to him.

I want to know how a native English speaker would say that.

And also I want to know, can I say the below statement when the moment I have finished the drawing,

> "It ***has taken*** me five years to fulfill the word I had given"

Comment: The usual expression is **to keep one's word** rather than **fulfill* it although there's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence. *The word I had given* has a poetic rather than an idiomatic ring to it. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+my+word

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thanks for your comment. The final action *"I've drawn your picture at last"* in the context is a finished action. So *"keep"* doesn't fit here I think. Because *"Keep one's word"* sounds like *"It took me five years to (start keeping) keep the words I had given"*. But here in my example, the action is a *"completed task"*. So I would like to know how a native English speaker would say this.

Comment: This sentence is idiomatic -- in the Bible, not in modern English. Also consider "fulfill my promise".

Comment: @LukeSawczak then how would say this. Please suggest me something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ronald Sole wrote, saying "give one's word" is idiomatic but has a poetic ring to it.

The poeticness is compounded by the use of "fulfill".

That word has two different connotations. When you fulfill an order or a shipment, it's modern and commercial.

But in the sense of fulfilling a promise (or a prophecy or prediction), it's poetic. That's why your sentence made me think of poetic Bible verses like [John 18:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2018%3A9&version=NIV):

> This happened so that the **words** he had spoken would be **fulfilled**.

If we replace both those elements in your original sentence, we might use any of these variations:

> It took me five years to keep my promise.
>
> It took me five years to make good on the promise I made.
>
> It took me five years to do what I said I would.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "It took me five years to do what I said I would." sounds simple and fine.